# getting error while using IN operator in cassandra 3.4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra version :- `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]`

My Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id1 text,
id2 text,
id3 text,
id4 text,
clinet_starttime timestamp,
avail_endtime timestamp,
starttime timestamp,
client_endtime timestamp,
code int,
status text,
total_time double,
PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2, id3, id4, client_starttime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id2 ASC, id3 ASC, id4 ASC, client_starttime ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Following query is working for me

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE client_starttime<1522832400000 AND client_starttime>1522831800000 AND id1='data1' AND id2='data2' AND id3='data3' AND id4 IN ('data5','data6','data7') ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But when I query using `starttime` and `avail_endTime` instead of `client_starttime` like

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE starttime<1522832400000 AND avail_endTime>1522831800000 AND id1='data1' AND id2='data2' AND id3='data3' AND id4 IN ('data5','data6','data7') ALLOW FILTERING;
```

getting the following error

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot restrict clustering columns by IN relations when a collection is selected by the query"
```

If I am not using `IN` operator , If I use `=` operator then its working fine

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE starttime<1522832400000 AND avail_endTime>1522831800000 AND id1='data1' AND id2='data2' AND id3='data3' AND id4 = 'data5'ALLOW FILTERING;
```

but I want to retrieve data for `data5, data6 and data7` same time.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to use `ALLOW FILTERING` - while it works for small datasets, but it will fail on big tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known Cassandra bug: [CASSANDRA-12654](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12654) - it's already fixed, but will be available only in version 4.0 for which there is no release date yet defined.