# Cassandra Statement containing IN, on table with a collection column type

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have a Cassandra table like the below:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ( 
name text, 
surname text, 
id_1 text, 
id_2 text, 
contents map< int, FROZEN<MAP<text, text>>>, 
PRIMARY KEY( (name, surname), id_1, id_2) )
```

**id_1** and **id_2** are clustering columns and i am trying to execute the below select query:

```
SELECT id_1,contents FROM my_table WHERE name='foo' and surname='bar' and id_1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

However this query does not work with the below error:

```
Cannot restrict clustering columns by IN relations when a collection is selected by the query
```

Is this because one of the tables column has a collection type (map)?

If i omit the 'contents' column from my SELECT statement this query works fine.

Is there any way this query can work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting error while using IN operator in cassandra 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647694/getting-error-while-using-in-operator-in-cassandra-3-4)

Comment: See answer to linked question...